# Understanding more about Hoc in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJs.I have been reading about Hoc in reactjs.I have a scenario where one TextEditor can connect to google cloud platform or aws for saving its content.I am thinkig of desiging it as

```
<GCP>
<TextEditor/>
</Gcp>
or 
<Aws>
<TextEditor/>
</AWS>
```

where  `<GCP>/<Aws>` will be a HOC and all the async operation will happen in the class function and It will pass as a prop to TextEditor.I want to know that is it the right way to design my component or there is some more design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render prop these state updates and the actions associated with it, for example :

```js
const Aws = ({children,initailState,...props})=>{

cosnt [state,setState]=useState(initailState)
const onSave = async (data) =>{
  const newState = await saveData(data) // an example service call
   setState(newState)
}

return (
      <div>
     {
      (typeof children === 'function') 
      ?
      children(state,onSave)
      :
      children 
      </div>
     )
}
```

and the AWS component(or the GCP) can be consumed:

```js
<Aws>
{(state,onSave)=> <TextEditor state={state} onSave={onSave} />}
</AWS>
```

> you can [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) the state updates and pass the callbacks as hocks to update the state, or you can use [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

in this case, the consumer components that use this component don't have to know about the AWS details, but it has the side effects (state changes in this case)

Comment: As per the Doc HOC doesn’t modify the input component, nor does it use inheritance to copy its behavior. So Is it  still valid to pass on save function(Aws/Gcp class) to text-editor as a Props, if yes then my design will be <GCP><TextEditor/></Gcp>.

Comment: this is a composition approach and, for JS we prefer to use the functional design instead of the oop design, and there is no way to pass or expose the AWS/GCP components attributes to a child component without explicitly passing the props or encapsulate the child with the parent